# How to share an Custom Image on LinkedIn Share

Tags: javascript, jquery, share, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to setup social share with LinkedIn JS API on a blog. The share function works fine but the image shared on the post is random. Instead is there a possibility to share a specific or custom image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own HTML button, with its own CSS styles and JS functionality, and then all you need is to hyperlink it:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

This doesn't just let you control the image, it lets you control every aspect of the new share button.

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Works fine:

[image]